# custom manager for base models.Model for filtering subclasses with differents attributes

Tags: django, inheritance, orm

Let's say I have the following classe which implement a base model for data with time intervals (I do not write here the whole implementation and I cannot use third-party libraries).

```py
class BaseHistorizationModel(models.Model):

    value = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    date_begin = models.DateField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)
    date_end = models.DateField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = [F("date_begin").asc(nulls_last=True)]

   @classmethod
    def get_values_between(cls, date_begin, date_end):
        instances = cls.get_instances_between(date_begin, date_end)
        return [(i.date_begin, i.value) for i in instances}
        
   @classmethod
    def get_instances_between(cls, date_begin, date_end):
        begin_overlap = cls._get_begin_overlap(date_begin, date_end)
        end_overlap = cls._get_end_overlap(date_begin, date_end)
        insides = cls.object.filter(
            date_begin__gte=date_begin,
            date_end__lte=date_end,
        )
        over = cls._get_overlap(date_begin, date_end)
        return to_list(
            over if over else (begin_overlap, insides, end_overlap) 
        )

   @classmethod
    def _get_begin_overlap(cls, date_begin, date_end):
        try:
            overlap = cls.objects.get(
                Q(date_begin__lt=date_begin)
                & Q(date_end__gt=date_begin)
                & Q(date_end__lt=date_end)
            )
         except cls.ObjectDoesNotExist:
             overlap = None
        return overlap

    ...
```

Then I have other classes that inherit from `BaseHistorizationModel`, such as:

```
class NbOccupant(BaseHistorizationModel):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    building = models.ForeignKey(
        Building,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="nb_occupants",
    )    

class Temperature(BaseHistorizationModel):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.ForeignKey(
        City,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="temperatures",
    )
```

I do not clearly see how I can use my method `get_values_between_date` for  my sublcasses. For those classes, I need to first filter my data with their own foreign key, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
nb_occupants = NbOccupant.get_values_between_date(start, end, building__name="palais de l'elysee")
temperatures = Temperature.get_values_between(start, end, city__name="Grenoble")
```

I ended up with the following:

```
class BaseHistorization(models.Model):
   ...
   @classmethod
    def get_values_between(date_begin, date_end, **extra_query):
        instances = cls.get_instances_between(date_begin, date_end, extra_query)
        return {i.date_begin: i.value for i in instances}

   ... 

    @classmethod
    def _get_begin_overlap(date_begin, date_end, extra_query):
        query = (
           Q(date_begin__lt=date_begin)
           & Q(date_end__gt=date_begin)
           & Q(date_end__lt=date_end)
        )
        try:
            overlap = cls.objects.filter(query, **extra_query)
        except cls.ObjectDoesNotExist:
            overlap = None
        return overlap
```

It seems to be a little bit complicated, I would need to pass extra_query through all my fonction up to `cls.objects.get` or `cls.objects.filter`. I have got a lot of those function calls. I think `CustomManager` could help me but I do not exactly see how. Or maybe I could do something else.

Comment: Can you show what exactly is this `get_mean_value` method supposed to do for atleast one of the class? It is not very clear what exactly your problem is here.

Comment: yes, I have edited my question. Hope it is better